# 3 types of asking SQL (without mappers type linq or nhibernate)

Tags: c#, sql

what is difference between these 3 types of asking SQL for data (not telling that odbc can ask different DB)

1.) ODBC dll: Microsoft.Data.ODBC

```
OdbcConnection cn;
OdbcCommand cmd;
string MyString;

MyString="Select ...";
cn= new OdbcConnection("Driver={SQL Server};Server=...;UID=...;PWD=...;Database=...;");
cn.Open();
cmd=new OdbcCommand(MyString,cn);
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    ....
}

reader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

second dll: System.Data.SqlClient

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["…"].ConnectionString);           
SqlDataReader rdr = null;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ..."

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              

while (rdr.Read())
{
   .....
}
rdr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

third: dll: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

```
Database context = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("..."); 
IDataReader dataReader = context.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text,"SELECT ...")

dataReader.Read();
var inputid = (int)dataReader["..."];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **ODBC** is the very old, long gone DB-access standard - don't use it unless you absolutely must. (it was "hip" back in the 1990's or so)
- **SqlClient** is the .NET bare-bones ADO.NET level of accessing SQL Server databases, and the foundation for all other technologies. It can basically do anything with SQL Server that you need to do - run data queries, run DDL queries, execute stored procedures and so forth. It's fairly basic and bare-bones, e.g. you have to type a lot of repeating, boring code yourself
- **EnterpriseLibrary.Data** is a layer on top of ADO.NET which simplifies common tasks by handling some of the repetitive code for you.

There are additional things on top of the ADO.NET foundation - things like NHibernate, Entity Framework and so forth - but the **SqlClient** / ADO.NET is really the basis for all current, modern database access (to SQL Server, mostly) in the .NET world

Answer (score 0):

- ODBC drivers are a sort of wrapper around ODBC, that is a wrapper over native db connection
- SqlConnection are the most direct way of talking to MSSQL server AFAIK
- DatabaseFactory is just a factory ( ehm ... ) that eventually uses SqlConnection when you talk with MSSQL Server.

Comment: I would avoid ODBC, for the other depends if you are creating a very simple application that will target for sure MSSQL, or if you are planning to change the DBEngine and your app is going to be a real world product, in such a case EF, or your own factory for DBConnection is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` is a wrapper around `System.Data.SqlClient`, so it adds some niceties to the built-in `SqlClient` functionality. As @Felice Pollano said, ODBC drivers wrap native DB connection, so I tend to avoid them.